# jquery ajax load not working in Chrome 35 or Safari 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Works in FF and IE. Only using server pages.
The page reloads instead of loading the ajax content. Sometimes displays a broken image icon before reloading, even though only text is output.

I went back and checked a different website that uses the same ajax syntax and found erratic behaviors in Chrome. Some text missing in the ajax content. A php error that went away on subsequent attempts (this may be unrelated).

Here is the ajax code:

```
var ajax_load = '<img src="/ajax-loader_big.gif" width="35px" alt="loading..." />';
var m = document.getElementById("MID").value;
$("#TxtContent").html(ajax_load).load("getMsg.php", {m: m});
```

It's called from this HTML:

```
<form method=post action="">
<input type="text" id="MID" name="MID" cols="6" autofocus ><br><br>
<button onclick="processMID();" >Find my message!</button>
</form>
```

I've seen lots of questions about similar problems with Chrome, but it usually has to do with the files running locally. I've yet to see someone asking about the page reloading.

I've tested to see if the called file is run (it is, at least it starts). And I've replaced the called file with a simple text echo.

I suspect the reload problem is an interaction issue between Chrome and the ajax returned

What irks me most, is the undependable behavior in the previous website with jquery load() and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the button is acting as a submit button. Use `return false;` to prevent this default behavior.

```
<button onclick="processMID();return false;" >Find my message!</button>
```

You can also change the form's action to prevent submission:

```
<form method=post action="javascript:void(0);">
```